# 2D Trajectory arc too weak Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Hello again StackOverflow, i am currently struggling with my trajectory arc code. My problem is that the arc is far too 'weak' meaning that it drops away to the floor almost straight away whilst my projectile flies off into the distance. Any help that you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

relevant Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ProjectileDrag : MonoBehaviour {

//variables for catapult
public float maxStretch = 3.0f;
public LineRenderer catapultLineFront;
public LineRenderer catapultLineBack;

private SpringJoint2D spring;
private Transform catapult;
private Ray rayToMouse;
private Ray leftCatapultToProjectile;
private float maxStretchSqr;
private float circleRadius;
private Vector2 prevVelocity;
private bool clickedOn = false;

//prediction line
int samples = 15;
float spacing = 0.1f;
private GameObject[] line;
private Vector3 home;
int force = 4;



void Awake(){
    spring = GetComponent<SpringJoint2D> ();
    catapult = spring.connectedBody.transform;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    LineRendererSetup ();
    rayToMouse = new Ray (catapult.position, Vector3.zero);
    leftCatapultToProjectile = new Ray (catapultLineFront.transform.position, Vector3.zero);
    maxStretchSqr = maxStretch * maxStretch;
    CircleCollider2D circle = collider2D as CircleCollider2D;
    circleRadius = circle.radius;

    line = new GameObject[samples];
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++){
        var go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        go.collider.enabled = false;
        go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2f,0.2f,0.2f);
        line[i] = go;
    }

    home = transform.position;
}

void FixedUpdate(){

    if (clickedOn)
            DisplayLine ();
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (clickedOn)
            Dragging ();

    if (spring != null) {
        if(!rigidbody2D.isKinematic && prevVelocity.sqrMagnitude > rigidbody2D.velocity.sqrMagnitude){
            Destroy (spring);
            rigidbody2D.velocity = prevVelocity;
        }
        if (!clickedOn)
            prevVelocity = rigidbody2D.velocity;

        LineRendererUpdate();
            } else {
        catapultLineFront.enabled = false;
        catapultLineBack.enabled = false;
            }

}

void LineRendererSetup(){
    catapultLineFront.SetPosition (0, catapultLineFront.transform.position);
    catapultLineBack.SetPosition (0, catapultLineBack.transform.position);


    catapultLineFront.sortingLayerName = "Foreground";
    catapultLineBack.sortingLayerName = "Foreground";


    catapultLineFront.sortingOrder = 3;
    catapultLineBack.sortingOrder = 1;

}

void OnMouseDown(){
    spring.enabled = false;
    clickedOn = true;
}

void OnMouseUp(){
    spring.enabled = true;
    rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
    clickedOn = false;
}

void Dragging(){
    Vector3 mouseWorldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    Vector2 catapultToMouse = mouseWorldPoint - catapult.position;

    if (catapultToMouse.sqrMagnitude > maxStretchSqr) {
            rayToMouse.direction = catapultToMouse;
        mouseWorldPoint = rayToMouse.GetPoint(maxStretch);
            }

    mouseWorldPoint.z = 0.0f;
    transform.position = mouseWorldPoint;

}

void LineRendererUpdate(){

    Vector2 catapultToProjectile = transform.position - catapultLineFront.transform.position;
    leftCatapultToProjectile.direction = catapultToProjectile;
    Vector3 holdPoint = leftCatapultToProjectile.GetPoint (catapultToProjectile.magnitude + circleRadius);
    catapultLineFront.SetPosition (1, holdPoint);
    catapultLineBack.SetPosition (1, holdPoint);

}

void DisplayLine(){
    line [0].transform.position = transform.position;
    Vector3 v3 = transform.position;
    float y = (force * (home - transform.position)).y;
    float t = 0.0f;
    v3.y = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 1; i < line.Length; i++) {
        v3 += force * (home - transform.position) * spacing;
        t += spacing;
        v3.y = y * t + 0.5f * Physics2D.gravity.y * t * t + transform.position.y;
        line[i].transform.position = v3;
            }
}
```

}

Image of problem (full power shot):

[image: Full power shot. Weak prediction line.]

Comment: Increasing `force` or decreasing `gravity` helps?

Comment: Whilst that does help, i was kinda hoping that there was an error somewhere that i could fix so that it scales properly rather than trial and error-ing it. :)

Comment: Are you increasing `force` while the `Vector2` of the projectile is moving away from its starting point?

Comment: I'm not seeing this part in your code.

Comment: Ah...no i am not, how should i go about implementing that? by checking what the catapultToProjectile.magnitude is?

Comment: You calculate the `Vector2` between the resting position of the projectile and its new position then get its magnitude and add it to `force`.

Comment: I am attempting to do this and cannot get it to work, how would you do it?

Comment: You can check my answer.

Comment: Can you share your fixed code, I have same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
private int actualFoce = 0;

void Update(){
   Vector2 distanceFromCatapult = Vector2(transform.position.x - catapult.x, transform.position.y - catapult.y);
   actualForce = distanceFromCatapult.magnitude + force;

   //then the rest of your code
}
```

And use actualForce in your `DisplayLine()` and for projecting your projectile.